# Closure inside a Common Lisp Macro

Tags: macros, common-lisp

In the following code how can i have the `x` and `y` variables to reflect the expressions given at macro call time?

```
(defmacro defrule (init-form &rest replication-patterns)
  (let (rule-table)
   `(destructuring-bind (p x y) ',init-form
       #'(lambda (w h) (list x y)))))
```

When expanding a call like:

```
(defrule (70 (* 1/2 w) (+ h 3)))
```

it returns:

```
(DESTRUCTURING-BIND (P X Y) '(70 (* 1/2 W) (+ H 3))
  #'(LAMBDA (W H) (LIST X Y)))
```

where the original expressions with `W` and `H` references are lost. I tried back-quoting the lambda function creation:

```
(defmacro defrule (init-form &rest replication-patterns)
  (let (rule-table)
    `(destructuring-bind (p x y) ',init-form
       `#'(lambda (w h) (list ,x ,y)))))
```

But a same call:

```
(defrule (70 (* 1/2 w) (+ h 3)))
```

expands to:

```
(DESTRUCTURING-BIND
    (P X Y)
    '(70 (* 1/2 W) (+ H 3))
  `#'(LAMBDA (W H) (LIST ,X ,Y)))
```

which returns a CONS:

```
#'(LAMBDA (W H) (LIST (* 1/2 W) (+ H 3)))
```

which can not be used by `funcall` and passed around like a function object easily. How can i return a function object with expressions i pass in as arguments for the `x y` part of the `init-form` with possible `W H` references being visible by the closure function?

Comment: This seems like poor design, requiring the user to know that the variables `W` and `H` are generated in the expansion.

Comment: This is part of an internal structure of a program, not meant to be used by the user. At the call time to this macro the `W H` variable are unknown, so i want to return a function which can be called with definite `W H` later on when they are available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting a cons because you have the backquotes nested.

You don't need backquote around `destructuring-bind`, because you're destructuring at macro expansion time, and you can do the destructuring directly in the macro lambda list.

```
(defmacro defrule ((p x y) &rest replication-patterns)
  (let (rule-table)
    `#'(lambda (w h) (list ,x ,y))))
```

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your code:

```
(defmacro defrule (init-form &rest replication-patterns)
  (let (rule-table)
   `(destructuring-bind (p x y) ',init-form
       #'(lambda (w h) (list x y)))))
```

You want a macro, which expands into code, which then **at runtime** takes code and returns a closure?

That's probably not a good idea.

Keep in mind: it's the macro, which should manipulate code at macro-expansion time. At runtime, the code should be fixed. See Barmar's explanation how to improve your code.